# When will the Python special method (i.e. magic method) __len__ be called?

Tags: python, magic-methods

I'm trying to make a Link-List Node class for a Link-List, as shown in the code:

```
class LNode:
    def __init__(self, data=None, pnext=None):
        self.data = data
        self.pnext = pnext

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.data} -> {self.pnext}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.data} -> {self.pnext}"

    def __len__(self):
        print("len method called...")
        cnt = 1
        return cnt

    def headInsert(self, nextNode):
        nextNode.pnext = self.pnext
        self.pnext = nextNode

    def headInsert_woh(self, nextNode):
        nextNode.pnext = self
        return nextNode

    def tailInsert(self, nextNode):
        print("tail-insert called...")
        tail = self
        while tail.pnext:
            tail = tail.pnext
        tail.pnext = nextNode
        return self

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.tailInsert(other)
```

After definition, I tried codes below:

```
a = LNode(1)
for i in range(2, 6):
    a += LNode(i)
print(a)
```

Strangely, **__len__** method will be called repeatedly and recursively when the **tail-insert** method is called, or when the node pointer of the Link-List node moves. As shown below:

```
tail-insert called......
tail-insert called......
len method called......
tail-insert called......
len method called......
len method called......
tail-insert called......
len method called......
len method called......
len method called......
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> None
```

But why? I thought __len__ is the implementation of BIF len(), why it will be called here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "I thought __len__ is the implementation of BIF len()" that is not strictly speaking true. `__len__` is a *hook* used by the built-in `len` method, and potentially in other cases, as described in the answers below

Answer (score 6):

This is because you're testing the truth value of `tail.pnext` as a `while` condition in this line:

```
while tail.pnext:
```

According to Python's documentation of [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
> either a `__bool__()` method that returns False or a `__len__()` method
> that returns zero, when called with the object.

Since your `LNode` class does not have a `__bool__` method defined, the `__len__` method is called instead for the truth value testing.

Comment: dangit, beat me to it. I would add an example of adding a `__bool__` method that demonstrates that this would take precedence over `__len__` if it is defined.

Comment: If the line is changed to `while tail.pnext is not None:` then `__len__` is not called since there is an explicit boolean expression.

Comment: @KellyBundy By misspelling "truth value" do you mean my verbiage of "truthiness"? It's a commonly used, even if informal, terminology, in the Python world. You can even find it in some PEP articles such as [PEP-572](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#special-casing-conditional-statements).

Comment: @md2perpe What do you mean with "explicit"?

Comment: @KellyBundy Indeed I see it more as a Python slang than something worthy of a formal documentation so yeah, it's fixed as recommended. :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy. `tail.pnext is not None` is an expression which clearly has a boolean value, while just `tail.pnext` does not. For the latter the boolean value is *implicit*, which means that it is not obvious, instead the boolean value of it comes from hidden evaluations.

Comment: @md2perpe Hmm, ok, yes, `is` definitely results in a `bool`. Unlike also for example `==`. Although that `bool` will then still get its truth value tested the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for `__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) (on the Data model page) states:

> Also, an object that doesn’t define a `__bool__()` method and whose `__len__()` method returns zero is considered to be false in a Boolean context.

Your

```
while tail.pnext:
```

does put `tail.pnext` in a Boolean context and evaluates its [truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Since your object doesn't have a `__bool__` method, Python tries `__len__` instead.

If you add a `__bool__` method that also prints such a message, you'll see that that gets called instead of `__len__` (for the code you showed - of course it would be called when using `len`).

Answer (score 0):

If you change your prints to:

```
def __len__(self):
    print("len method called on", self.data)
    # ...

def tailInsert(self, nextNode):
    print("tail-insert called on", self.data, "for", nextNode.data)
    # ...
```

After running your code, you'll get:

```
tail-insert called on 1 for 2
tail-insert called on 1 for 3
len method called on 2
tail-insert called on 1 for 4
len method called on 2
len method called on 3
tail-insert called on 1 for 5
len method called on 2
len method called on 3
len method called on 4
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> None
```

Which shows that every time you call `tailInsert` and check `tail.pnext` if `tail.pnext` is not `None` the `__len__` is called on it as it's in front of a `while`.